# Laravel subqueries using left join

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

How can I write below mysql query using laravel4

There are two tables
Table 1 is fee_category with fields:

```
id | Category
1  | A
2  | B
3  | C
4  | D
```

Table 2 is fee_charge with fields:

```
id | std_id | particularID | CategoryID | assign | amount
1  | 1      | 1            | 1          | 0      | 1000  
2  | 1      | 1            | 2          | 1      | 12000  
3  | 1      | 2            | 3          | 0      | 3000  
4  | 1      | 2            | 4          | 0      | 10  
5  | 2      | 1            | 2          | 0      | 100  
6  | 2      | 2            | 3          | 0      | 120
```

I want to write below query in laravel4

```
SELECT fee_category.id
, fee_category.Category
, X.std_id
, X.particularID
, X.CategoryID
, X.assign
, X.amount
 FROM fee_category
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT * FROM fee_charge
     WHERE fee_charge.std_id = 1 
     AND fee_charge.particularID = 1) AS X 
     ON x.CategoryID = fee_category.id
```

My attempt is:

```
DB::table('fee_category')
->leftJoin((function ($query) use ($std_id, $particularID) {
    $query->DB::raw("(SELECT * FROM fee_charge
         WHERE fee_charge.std_id = $std_id 
         AND fee_charge.particularID = $particularID) AS X"
}), function($join)
                {$join->on('fee_category.id', '=', 'X.CategoryID');})
->select('fee_category.id', 'fee_category.Category', 'X.std_id'
, 'X.particularID', 'X.CategoryID', 'X.assign', 'X.amount', 'X.dateOfCharge', 'X.dueDate'
)
->get();
```

Getting error as T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM

Answer (score 0):

Why are you not using Eloquent ORM?
https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent

You will have an eloquent called "FeeCharges" with a foreign key has the id of "FeeCategory".

In the FeeCharges eloquent model, put the "belongsTo" method for relate the external key "CategoryID" with the model, you must rename the column with "category_id".

In Laravel 4 is

```
    public function category() {

        return $this->belongsTo('FeeCategory');

    }
```

So, when we'll call the "category" method in the FeeCharges model (ex. FeeCharges::find(1)->category), this will return the related category record.

Build your queryes will be very simple with eloquent.
In your case, the example below, will do the job for you:

```
    $objects = FeeCharges::with('category')
      ->whereRaw('std_id = '.$std_id.' and particularID ='.$particularID)
      ->get();
```

And that's it!